# SharePoint 2013 - The content processing component failed to process the security descriptor of the item

Tags: search, 2013

I have a small farm one FE server one AP server

I have started to configure the Search for the 2 existing webapps (both running sites in SSL). Both are configured the same and using the same Search Service application. One of them is used for mysites.

For one webapp everything is fine  no errors everything is being crawled and indexed properly. However for another webapp more than 50% of errors with the current messages from crawl logs:

The content processing component failed to process the security descriptor of the item.

From the server logs in verbose I have that kind of error messages:

> 04/18/2013 16:39:43.15    mssearch.exe (0x04BC)
>     0x3904  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Gatherer Service
>     fus3    Medium      Transaction failed in plugin IPOC Url
>   sts4s://XXXX.XXXX/siteurl=/siteid={307d29bb-3ad6-47c3-9102-0d3d89394113}/weburl=cop/TEST/SC/webid={cd73a06f-35dd-4e17-aef8-e5a4c333fbf0}/listid={de5b203b-8c26-45e2-b500-c4ac80fbbb2e}/viewid={3238b500-db09-49e3-bd37-dc0c5ddc5b15} Error 0x80040dd6  [gthrtrx.cxx:950] 
>   search\native\gather\gthrsvc\gthrtrx.cxx  4a36a644-fdc4-4c75-adb0-3f4b8215e3e0
>
> 04/18/2013 16:39:43.15    mssearch.exe (0x04BC)
>     0x3904  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin
>     af7za   High        CSSFeedersManager::session_CallbackReceived: Document
>   6125 processing failed. Error messages: The input ACL is invalid (302
>   / 1622).; , errorID = 2147749334  hostName = DMZ-XXXXXX nodeName =
>   ContentProcessingComponent1

I ran a quite a few searches on those errors, but to no avail. Any ideas would be welcome

thanks

Comment: did u find a solution for this? i'm having the same issue but with no clue of the cause?

Comment: Yeah. Me too. :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with the "The input ACL is invalid" one web application. We did a user migration and this migration causes an invalid group claim. The solution was to check the root web for invalid users via PowerShell

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://mysharepoint
$web.AllUsers | Where { $_.UserLogin.EndsWith("|") }
```

The result was an empty group claim "c:0+.w|". After determinating the invalid user I user migrated it again to a valid group claim:

```
$user = $web.AllUsers | Where { $_.UserLogin.EndsWith("|") }
$user = $user[4] # Index of the invalid user
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias "c:0+.w|S-1-3-....." -IgnoreSID -confirm:$false
```

The user migration has thrown an exception but the migration executed. After that I was able to start a Full Crawl on the web application without any errors.